# Yii image resize getting rotated image

Tags: image, yii, gd

I am uploading image from Iphone. Using following code to resize.

```
$image=Yii::app()->image->load('images/uploads/album_photos/'.$file_name);
 $image->resize(300, 300);
$image->save('images/uploads/album_photos/thumb/'.$file_name);
```

I am not using any rotate function. But still it is getting rotated.

Comment: I had a similar issue a while ago.
Did you check your uploaded image - at my issue it was rotated already while uploading.
Otherwise it could be a bug - but strange bug. Did you try `$image->resize(300,300)->rotate(0);` ?

Comment: no, i didnt try it, i used another method